# Need to power an AC Motor from either 120VAC or 220VAC

Tags: motor, transformer, fan, step-down

I am trying to modify a convection oven into a solder re-flow oven.  One of my design requirements is it needs to work on both 120VAC and 220VAC (I will need to use it in the USA and over seas).  Right now I am working on powering the convection fan motor.

The existing motor is a 120VAC 60Hz 0.35 Amp motor (I think an asynchronous motor)

These are the only specs I have for the motor, it came installed in the oven:
https://www.zhaoli-motor.com/sale-13995231-small-convection-oven-fan-motors-yj61-200-cl-h-120v-60hz.html

Powering the fan in the USA is no problem, just feed it 120VAC.  However, when the device is on 220VAC, I will need to step down the voltage.

I am thinking about using a 2:1 step-down auto transformer like this one:
https://octopart.com/datasheet/n-1x-triad+magnetics-15850

However, from my research I am worried that there will be problems driving the inductive load with a transformer,
https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transformer/transformer-loading.html
But, honestly I don't understand all of the math involved.

I am planning on using a SPDT switch to change the input power to the motor from

1. AC source directly when on 120VAC
2. Secondary coils from the step down transformer which will be powered from 220VAC

If this is option is not feasible, then what type of motor would be easier to interface with different voltage levels.  (I could power the motor from DC because I will need an AC/DC converter anyway for alternative functions)

Thanks in advance.

Gavin

Comment: You should replace the motor with one that accepts a wide input voltage range. There are nowadays electronically commutated motors (ECM's) with a wide input voltage. In essence they are an  AC-DC converter followed by a BLDC controller.

Comment: In US you have between phases 208 or 240V.

Answer (score 0):

A transformer is one option, you can compensate the inductive load with a capacitor if the phase is off significantly, but that shouldn't be a problem for most motors (I could be wrong). Measure the phase of your setup when you test it.

A better way would be to find a motor that has two coils in it, then you use a 110V/220V selector switch on the back (the user must select the voltage of the switch, but this is common on many products).

I once designed a product with an auto voltage selector that would select between 110V/220V coils on an AC fan, but it ended up needing a big transformer to drive the relays so we decided to go with a DPDT switch.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I didn't realize correcting the phase could be as simple as just adding a capacitor.  I will most likely use the DPDT switch as you suggested.

Comment: It might be more than a cap, look up snubber

Answer (score 0):

Addition of an autotransformer would take care of the voltage.

[image]

The autotransformer should be rated as follows:

- Input: 220 - 230 - 240 V 50 Hz
- Output: 120 V --A

The frequency is 50 Hz in most countries.

However fan speed would be a problem since a 60Hz fan would run 20% slower at 50 Hz.

Comment: Autotransformer is a very good solution.  Thank you.